# Rails code reference checker on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've noticed that when I deployed my project to Heroku that its able to find coding errors where I had forgotten to change calls to methods that I had refactored (ie changes to method name or signature).  It just failed to deploy until the code has been fixed.

This seems to suggest that Heroku has some sort of preprocessor or interpreter built in that does a pseudo "compile" on the code before it allows it finish deployment.  Is anyone else aware of this?

Is there a gem out there that will allow me to run a quick sanity check on my code?

Naturally, there needs to be specs / unit tests of course, but having another tool in the toolbox can't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that it's more the differing behaviour of how a Rails application is loaded/started in production mode as opposed to development mode.

If you start you local application in production mode locally you should see the same behaviour as on Heroku.

Comment: This is because a Rails development environment will typically employ lazy loading so that you don't have to restart your server every time you make changes to a controller, model, etc.